# Help evaluating long definite integral.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, order-statistics

First, thanks for your time and input. In some research, I evaluate the following integral 
$$\int_0^1 x (n-1) n v^{-2n}(v-x)\lambda^{-n}(v-2x+\lambda v)(\lambda v-x)(x(v+\lambda v-x))^{n-2} dx$$ where v>0  $\lambda$>1 and n>2. using Mathematica and the solution is very ugly (including hypergeometric functions).

I was wondering if anyone could help advise me on how to start to evaluate this integral by hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, simply rewrite your function. Here's how to do it by hand (as you asked):

First let's write:

$$\displaystyle I=\int_0^1 x (n-1) n v^{-2n}(v-x)\lambda^{-n}(v-2x+\lambda v)(\lambda v-x)(x(v+\lambda v-x))^{n-2} dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

I'll just get rid of all the constant terms and put them on the side:

$f(x)=\left((n-1)nv^{-2n}\lambda^{-n}\right)\left(x(v-x)(v-2x+\lambda v)(\lambda v-x)x^{n-2}(v+\lambda v-x)^{n-2}\right)$

Now let's introduce some notations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}\left((n-1)nv^{-2n}\lambda^{-n}\right)=A \\ v+\lambda v=B\end{array}\right.$$

Replace in $I$:

$$\displaystyle I=\int_0^1 Ax(v-x)(B-2x)(\lambda v-x)x^{n-2}(B-x)^{n-2}dx$$

Now get rid of this constant term $A$ and call this new function in the integral $g$:

$$\displaystyle I=A\int_0^1 (v-x)(B-2x)(\lambda v-x)x^{n-1}(B-x)^{n-2}dx=A\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

Expand $g$:

$$g(x)=(v-x)(B-2x)(\lambda v-x)x^{n-1}(B-x)^{n-2}$$
$$=(vB-(B+2v)x+2x^2)(\lambda v-x)x^{n-1}(B-x)^{n-2}$$
$$=((v^2B\lambda)-x(vB+(B+2v)\lambda v)+x^2(2\lambda v+B+2v)-2x^3)x^{n-1}(B-x)^{n-2}$$

Add some more notations (just because I don't want to carry all these constants around):

$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(v^2B\lambda)=C_1 \\ (vB+(B+2v)\lambda v)=C_2 \\ (2\lambda v+B+2v)=C_3 \end{array}\right.$$

Your function looks a lot better now:

$$g(x)=\left(C_1x^{n-1}-C_2x^{n}+C_3x^{n+1}-2x^{n+2}\right)(B-x)^{n-2}$$

The "hard" part is the $(B-x)^{n-2}$, but not that hard actually, because you can write it this way:

$$\displaystyle(B-x)^{n-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}(-x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}x^k$$

So $g$ becomes:

$$g(x)=\left(C_1x^{n-1}-C_2x^{n}+C_3x^{n+1}-2x^{n+2}\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}x^k$$

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\left(C_1x^{n-1}-C_2x^{n}+C_3x^{n+1}-2x^{n+2}\right)x^k$$

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\left(C_1x^{k+n-1}-C_2x^{k+n}+C_3x^{k+n+1}-2x^{k+n+2}\right)$$

Let's go back to the integral:

$$\displaystyle I=A\int_0^1 g(x)dx$$
$$\displaystyle I=A\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\left(C_1x^{k+n-1}-C_2x^{k+n}+C_3x^{k+n+1}-2x^{k+n+2}\right) dx$$
$$\displaystyle I=A\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\int_0^1 \left(C_1x^{k+n-1}-C_2x^{k+n}+C_3x^{k+n+1}-2x^{k+n+2}\right) dx$$
$$\displaystyle I=A\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\times J_k$$

where $\displaystyle J_k=\int_0^1 \left(C_1x^{k+n-1}-C_2x^{k+n}+C_3x^{k+n+1}-2x^{k+n+2}\right) dx$

Now you have a simple polynomial to integrate:

$$\displaystyle J_k=\left[\frac{C_1}{k+n}x^{k+n}-\frac{C_2}{k+n+1}x^{k+n+1}+\frac{C_3}{k+n+2}x^{k+n+2}-\frac{2}{k+n+3}x^{k+n+3}\right]_0^1$$

$$\displaystyle J_k=\frac{C_1}{k+n}-\frac{C_2}{k+n+1}+\frac{C_3}{k+n+2}-\frac{2}{k+n+3}$$

And thus you have:

$$\displaystyle I=A\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(-1)^k{n-2 \choose k}B^{n-2-k}\left(\frac{C_1}{k+n}-\frac{C_2}{k+n+1}+\frac{C_3}{k+n+2}-\frac{2}{k+n+3}\right)$$

You can replace your values $A$,$B$,$C_1$,$C_2$ and $C_3$ and get your result (which I won't write here).

I admit it's still pretty ugly but at least you only have simple fractions and sums (and binomial terms). But with a function like yours you can't just expect a nice and clean solution ;)

Comment: My love for you is undying. Seriously thank you so very much. I will report back after I practice this a few times.

Comment: +1, @BorderedHessian If you love him that much, you should upvote (or perhaps also accept) his answer, that's a lot of effort :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did just that (new here). I wonder why Mathematica gave me such a nutty answer?

Comment: I came back to ask- am I missing something or did the initial x on the first line of the answer get lost in translation somewhere?

Comment: Oh yes it did, well spotted. I'll edit it, just changes some exponents and thus the fractions at the end, nothing much though.

Comment: Follow up- when I plot this function numerically in mathematica, it appears to be non-positive when it (in theory) should be non-negative. When I use the solution Mathematica gives me (involving hypergeometric functions), I get a result that is more agreeable.

Comment: Are you sure about your plot ? Because I tried it with $v=1.3$, $\lambda=2.1$ and $n=5$ which verify the properties. And indeed $f$ is always positive between $0$ and $1$ so $I$ should be non-negative. But when I compute $I$ with the formula I get $I=0.5628$ which is indeed non-negative.

Comment: Hey Dolma, did you compute this by hand(low probability event)? Or did you use software? I STILL can't get Mathematica to evaluate it properly. I suspect operator error on my part! If you did it in R/MatLab/Maple/Gauss/GAMS/(your favorite math environment here) could you share your code? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Border, the thing with sums like these is that hypergeometric functions happen to be the most compact way to express them. That being said, for computational purposes, Dolma's result is more practical.

Comment: @J.M.- Yea I am thankful to have a result that has a finite number of steps, haha! I just wish I could get the thing to work properly for me in Mathematica! What are the implications of having a solution that is not closed form? Am I correct in saying that a solution with a hypergeometric function involved isn't closed form? Thanks for helping a new guy! [I cross posted my programming troubles with this function here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23918/function-should-be-positive-is-negative-spot-my-error-please) hoping to get some help on the programming end.

Comment: @J.M. I added the Mathematica solution to the original post, if you were interested. I'd love to hear any other insight you have about this! Eager ears here.

Comment: @Border, "closed form" is in the eye of the beholder. I happen to be in the camp that thinks hypergeometric functions are admissible closed forms, and then there are people who eschew every other function that wasn't taught to them in secondary school...

Comment: @J.M. Is there any way I could get a "for dummies" version of what I am really doing when I use the hypergeometric function? I am in graduate school and use math regularly, though it's an applied field (economics) so I rarely get a chance to learn about what is REALLY going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Border, since you seem green on this, I'd suggest looking at Graham/Knuth/Patashnik's *Concrete Mathematics*, where they talk a bit about hypergeometric functions. For seeing how to manipulate them, you'll want to see the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/).

Comment: @J.M. I was also really "excited" about the whole binomial expansion part too. I didn't know you could do that! Haha. Thanks for the book recommendation, I will look into them ASAP.